# jQuery Validate and dynamic add rules using ajax remote issue. (possible var scope?)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am having difficulty getting the following piece of code to work as expected:

```
var counter = 0;
$('#add_row').click(function(e) {

    $('input[name="user_email[' + counter + ']"]').rules("add", {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: {
            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                user_email: function(Counter) {
                    return $('input[name="user_email[' + counter + ']"]').val();
                },
            },
        },
    });

    Counter++;
});
```

Below line returns undefined

```
return $('input[name="user_email[' + counter + ']"]').val();
```

While without the variable Counter it returns the value from the form input field as expected. But then it's no longer dynamic.

Eg.

```
return $('input[name="user_email[0]"]').val();
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:** *"Below line returns undefined"*

```
return $('input[name="user_email[' + counter + ']"]').val();
```

Your error is a moot point, as these lines are totally superfluous...

```
data: {
    user_email: function(Counter) {
        return $('input[name="user_email[' + counter + ']"]').val();
    },
},
```

You don't need the `data` option, because the `remote` method automatically sends the value of this field by default.  Typically the `data` option is used if you needed to send *additional* data along with the field value, such as the password field along with the username, which is clearly not the case here.

Simply remove the entire `data` option.

---

You've also mixed up the case sensitivity of the counter variable.

You have `var counter`, but then later you increment `Counter++`.  These are spelled the same, but they're also case-sensitive, so `Counter++` needs to be changed to `counter++`.

---

This should be working as expected...

```
var counter = 0;

$('#add_row').click(function(e) {
    $('input[name="user_email[' + counter + ']"]').rules("add", {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: {
            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'post',
            cache: false
        }
    });
    counter++;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your response.

My intention behind adding the data: was to send user_email rather than user_email[?].

I seem to have achieved what I wanted with the following:

```
var input_email = $('input[name="user_email[' + counter + ']"]');
    input_email.rules("add", {
        required: true,
        email: true,

        remote: {
            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
           data: {
                user_email: function() {
                    return input_email.val();
                },
            },
        },
    });

    counter++;
```

Seems like using the var counter in the element name didn't work.